# Is it possible to set next slide in revealjs?

Tags: reveal.js

I am teaching in a team learning focused class and am trying to make a self passed session that will have units. I can't seem to figure out how to set the next slide so I can do the following with my presentation:

```
1>2>3>4
->5>6>7
->8>9>10
```

Can you please help me out